# javascript showdown, markdown not parsing correctly

Tags: php, javascript, markdown

I have a confusing problem.

I have two files, both that run showdown. However, it seems that only one file parses correctly.

Here's the deal.

[File 1](http://pastie.org/631525) is run through PHP and AJAX.

[File 2](http://pastie.org/631526) is grabbed via an AJAX request. The file that processes the ajax request contains this code.

Here is the [ajax](http://pastie.org/631527)

As you can see, the jQuery code that puts the details onto the screen are exactly the same apart from the variables and the JSON string instead of a direct string from the database.

Now file #1 doesn't parse the markdown correctly, where file two does...

Here is a screenshot of files #1 and #2

**File #1**

[image: file one not working]

**File #2**

[image: file two working]

Any idea on what could possibly be causing this? Also, any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

So it seems it was the parsing of the line breaks in the file... However we have changed it from 
 as this is causing the issue of the markdown parsing incorrectly to double escaped

so it now reads

```
$copy = preg_replace("/\n/", "\\\\n", $js_r->copy);
$copy = preg_replace("/\r/", "\\\\r", $copy);
```

which works correctly and parses both files efficiently

Comment: Ok, glad it worked out well. By the way you may want to consider using str_replace instead of preg_replace as it is much faster (non regex).

Comment: i did take up your advise after i posted that ... i'm all for saving resources... thanks for pointing me in the right direction anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because in file 2 you have:

```
  $copy = preg_replace('^(.*)\n(.*)^', '$1<br />$2', $result['copy']);
  $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $result['copy']);
```

Which ignores the first preg_replace(). You want:

```
  $copy = preg_replace('^(.*)\n(.*)^', '$1<br />$2', $result['copy']);
  $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $copy);
```

Which you have correctly implemented in file 1. This could mean that file 1's behaviour is correct and file 2's behaviour is actually incorrect, depending on the way you look at it.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment:

Replace (in file 1):

```
   $copy = preg_replace('^(.*)\n(.*)^', '$1<br />$2', $js_r->copy);
   $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $copy);
```

With

```
   $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $js_r->copy);
```

Does that achieve the desired effect?

Comment: ok, but if i change that in file 1 (which is the one that isn't working) then i won't be getting the desired effect in either?

Comment: Well do the opposite in file 1 then, replace $copy = preg_replace('^(.*)\n(.*)^', '$1<br />$2', $js_r->copy);
   $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $copy); with 
   $copy = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '$1<br />$2', $js_r->copy);

I apologize for the lack of code formatting in comments.

Comment: it could work, but then as in another question i had that originally we came to the conclusion that the parsing of \n is required, otherwise it will break my javascript that i have. i'm out the office at the moment so when i get back i'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Yeah I found that quite odd in your code, you could just simply do a $code = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $js_r->copy); That's 2 lines in 1 and better performance. Not entirely sure why you decided to use regular expressions for this, as that is overkill.

Comment: as i imagined, that has now broken the first file as in the same problem i had with the original question